# What to do about repeatedly changing question?

Tags: discussion

This post is motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465777/implications-of-fermats-last-theorem-question/) question. OP first stated the question as:

" Does Fermat's Last Theorem or Euler's proof for the case n = 3 imply that $x*a^3+y*b^3 = c^3$ has no solutions in integers for $a,b,c$ positive integers and integers $x$ and $y$? Thank you.."

There were answers adressing this. After the answers happened, he changed the assumptions in the comments:

"I should add the condition that a,b,c,x,y cannot be 1."

After the proper changings on answers, he further changed the hypotheses:

"and the gcd(a,b) = 1."

How to proceed on this behaviour?

Comment: I usually delete my answer and any comments I've made.

Comment: Vote to close as PSQ?

Comment: @Did Sorry... what means PSQ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault: PSQ = Problem Statement Question, i.e. a question that merely states a problem without showing effort in the form of personal thought *or research* or whatever.

Comment: @Did That would go under the "This question is missing context or other details" criteria?

Comment: This is the idea, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if someone changes a question enough to invalidate previous answers, the question should be put on hold, especially if it happens more than once per question. These are not good questions.

This is related to a recent question, "what to do about accidental trivial answers?". I think if the content of the question changes, it should be a new question.

Comment: I basically agree. I would add though that answerers should make a reasonable effort to note and correct trivial oversights (in a comment for example) rather than "to exploit" a typo to get in a cheap answer. [This is a general remark not necessarily applicable to the specific question that motivated the question.]

Comment: You probably mean this question, right? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21126/questions-with-accidental-trivial-answers You seem to consider it related to this question (and I agree). So adding link to it seem like a logical thing to do.